# Elastic search with 2 indexes or any other method?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

We are managing two big sites
First containing all products information And second is containing only price of products.

First site JSON example

```
"Name": "Nokia",
"Price":"123",
"number":"a-788" 
"status":0,
```

and so on....

Second site JSON

```
"number":"a-788",
"price":"125",
"Status":1
```

I need both site JSON info but price will come from second site and where product status is 1.

Question is that

1. should I use indexes for each site because there may be lot of data?
2. how will it be manage query string?

Comment: Where are you currently storing the above mentioned information?

Comment: You need all the information in a stand-alone doc for it to be searchable as a whole. Hence, while indexing for a particular id, you can fetch the details from both the sites, create a doc by merging the information and then search on it.

Comment: rahulroc : One shitty question ,merging the information will create another index or not?